# PHP: in-memory searching

Tags: php, memcached

My PHP application needs to support Ajax calls from web browsers that provide a controller function with a search string. That search string is searched against an in-memory "array" of names + IDs. When a name is found, the NAME + ID is added to the return result for the AJAX call.

Initially that Name + ID resides in a database.

I am looking for best practices where every instance of PHP server loads up the list from the database, lazily, once, on the first call and conducts the sub-string search in memory for all subsequent searches.

IS memcached good for this? I know it's an in-memory key-value repository, but can it handle the sub-string search? Is there another best-practice I can use for this?

Comment: Either you are describing a rather sophisticated implementation of a daemon written in PHP but don't understand how to solve a relatively trivial problem in data management or you you have no idea how PHP works in a conventional webserver implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached doesn't have such functionality, it only allows to access value by known key. Value is transparent for the memcached.

To effectively match sub-string it is better to look at the storage engines that support secondary indexes such as [tarantool](http://tarantool.org)

If expected size of the value is not too big, maybe naive PHP function would be suffucient.